# Visual Studio Express 2013 GUI issues

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I am having some weird graphical issues in the Visual Studio Express 2013 edition (C++ Project) where when hovering over some things it shows an enlarged sprite over the whole window until I resize the window or move the window somewhere else and then back again.

An example of a 'normal' window (Memory 1 to be specific)
[image]

Now I will hover over a value so it shows the little hover box with the value (I am not entirely sure what this is called) but is shown in the next screenshot.
[image]

As soon as I move my cursor away from the popup box showing 00|0-> ('->' representing a pin) VS2013 freaks out and shows a very large stretched out (looks as if its a blown up sprite sheet of the characters?) across the whole window.
[image]

Things I have tried

1. Closed and reopened VS2013 -> still not working
2. Turned PC off and on again -> still not working
3. Uninstalled VS2013 and reinstalled -> still not working
4. Tried to change the font from Consolas (Default) to Times New Roman -> still not working

Computer Specs)

1. Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3930K CPU @ 3.20GHz
2. Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit
3. ASUS P9X79 WS (motherboard)
4. 32GB RAM
5. Geforce GTX Titan 6GB
6. Monitor Resolution: 1920x1080

Note) This isn't only limited to the Memory 1 window.

Comment: check that windows and your graphics card drivers are up to date.

Comment: @Poldie Windows is up to date and my graphics card is up to date too.

Comment: Not asolution, just a note: full Visual Studio 2013 Community edition is now availble for free: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx . Maybe it's only Express edition problem..?

Comment: @VincasDargis Just downloaded the installer and a similar problem happens on the installer too. http://i.stack.imgur.com/hOGRo.png

Comment: Can you try a different resolution or colour/bit depth?

Comment: Tried all the resolutions and bit depths to no avail (added computer specs to OP)

Comment: What is the screen resolution? Maybe a 4K issue?

Comment: Any 'quick view' plugins maybe? My guess it is trying to render the memory as a bitmap.

Comment: @leppie it's a totally fresh install with no plugins or addons installed

Comment: @user3045798 Not really sure what else to suggest! Safe mode, although not sure what that'll prove; perhaps that'll point at a driver problem even if it's up to date.  Do you have any unusual accessibility settings (in Windows)?

Comment: May be it would be useful to report bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio